# Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

Okay so, I `npm run build` my application, drag the build files into tizon studio.
Run the application...
I get the error:

> 2.bd938b3f.chunk.js:79798 Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function

The same behavior is shown on any Samsung and Tizon model I've tested this on.

I've tried switching out `Object.values` with `Object.map`,
which returns "the same" error.

> 2.bd938b3f.chunk.js:79798 Uncaught TypeError: Object.map is not a function

I have not been able to find an answer to fix this.
Any help with finding an answer would be massively appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!

```js
if (!le) {
    (function () {
        for (var e = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script"), t = 0, n = Object.values(e); t < n.length; t++) {
            var r = n[t];
            if (r.src && r.src.includes(te))
                return r
        }
        return null
    })() || function (e) {
        var t = document.createElement("script");
        t.src = te + "?l=" + e,
            t.async = !0,
            document.head.appendChild(t)
    }
            (ue),
        function (e) {
            var t = [];
            Array.isArray(window[e]) ? t = window[e] : window[e] = t
        }
            (ue);
    var r = ne(se, ue, ce),
        i = r.wrappedGtag,
        a = r.gtagCore;
    ie = i,
        re = a,
        le = !0
}
```

Comment: What browser & version are you using? These functions may not be supported.

Comment: @James I'm not a 100% sure. 
Its not running on a browser, its running as an application.
I'm aware that smart TV applications are basically browser windows.
All the tv's I've tested have been factory reset beforehand.
So it should be the default used for applications.

Comment: In that case it's more than likely just an incompatibility problem, you would need to understand what browser engine they are using, either way you will need to either use different code or use a polyfill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samsung's TizenOS's javascript isn't as up-to-date as it could be, and according to [this](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/art00015/index) looks to not be actively supported.

You can use [`react-app-polyfill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) to provide any missing functionalities.

We use the following in our root `index.jsx` as the "kitchen sink" of polyfills

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Object.values()` is not supported in your developing environment. Try adding this polyfill on top of your script file: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own values function if the node version is too low.

```
if (!Object.values) {
    Object.values = function values(O) {
        return Object.keys(O).map(k=>O[k]);
    };
}
```